# Is there a way to have a loop continue while waiting for a user's input without stopping the loop?

Tags: c++, loops, user-input

I'm trying to create a clock that will update every second, and if the user presses a button a menu will pop up allowing them to adjust the time.

I currently have a clock that updates every second, as well as the menu to that adjusts it, however when I combine the two together, the clock stops updating while I'm waiting for the user to input something. Is there any way to have the clock continue to loop and only stop once there is any user input? This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

void ReadUserInputClock(int& addTime) {
    int seconds = 1;
    int minutes = 60;
    int hours = 3600;
    char userInput;
    {   
        cout << " ___________________________" << endl;
        cout << "|Press '1' to add 1 second  |" << endl;
        cout << "|Press '2' to add 2 second  |" << endl;
        cout << "|Press '3' to add 3 second  |" << endl;
        cout << "|Press 'q' to quit          |" << endl;
        cout << " ___________________________" << endl;
        cin >> userInput;
        if (userInput == '1') {
            addTime = seconds;
        }
    
        else if (userInput == '2') {
            addTime = minutes;
        }
    
        else if (userInput == '3') {
            cout << '3';
            addTime = hours;
        }

        else if (userInput == 'q') {
            exit(0);
        }
        
        else {
            addTime = 0;
            cout << "No change." << endl;
        }

    }
}

void DisplayTime (int userTime) {
    char stopProgram = 'g';
    int timeYear;
    int timeMonth;
    int timeDay;
    int timeHour;
    int timeMinute;
    int timeSecond;
    struct tm *tim;
    time_t rawTime = time(NULL) + userTime;
    tim = localtime (&rawTime);
    timeYear = (tim->tm_year + 1900);
    timeMonth = (tim->tm_mon + 1);
    timeDay = tim->tm_mday;
    timeHour = (tim-> tm_hour - 5);
    timeMinute = tim->tm_min;
    timeSecond = tim->tm_sec;
    cout << "                       " << timeYear << "-" << setw(2) << timeMonth << "-" << setw(2) << timeDay << endl;
    cout << "_______________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "|     12-Hour Clock     |     |     24-Hour Clock     |" << endl;
    cout << "|                       |     |                       |" << endl;
    
    
    if (timeHour > 12) 
   {
       cout << "|      " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << timeHour - 12 << ":" << setw(2) << timeMinute << ":" << setw(2) << timeSecond << " PM" << "      |";
    }
    else 
   {
        cout << "|      " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << timeHour << ":" << setw(2) << timeMinute << ":" << setw(2) << timeSecond << " AM" << "      |";
   }
    cout << "     " ;
    cout << "|        " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << timeHour << ":" << setw(2) << timeMinute << ":" << setw(2) << timeSecond << "       |" << endl;
    cout << "_______________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "                  " << "Press 'm' for menu" << endl;

    cout << endl;
    
    //cout << string(50, '\n');
    }

void userClock() {
    int addTime = 0;
    int tempTime = 0;
    string input;
    while (addTime != -1) 
    {
        while (getline(cin, input)) {
            if (input.empty()) {
                DisplayTime(tempTime);
                sleep(1)
            }
        ReadUserInputClock(addTime);
        tempTime = tempTime + addTime;
        input.clear();
    }
    }
}





int main()
{
   userClock();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: So on an extremely low-resource system, I would have a loop (which runs _much_ faster than the clock output) which simply does two things: check if the clock needs to be updated, and checks if the user has provided input yet. Using that loop (or even a hardware interrupt!), you can simply react as soon as you see user input. Keep in mind this is a greedy solution,. you should consider doing a thread sleep for some amount of time to conserve resources

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, and `std::condition_variable`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but isn't that what my userClock() function is? its a loop with the sleep function, looking for any input from the user to run ReadUserInput() otherwise it just runs the displayClock() function, or at least that's what it's supposed to do



Sam, I don't unfortunately, this is my first time working with c++, and it's my first assignment